Animated show where people have a source of energy which helps them transform into beasts and the main protagonist is searching for his dad
I remember one episode where the main protagonist and his two friends went to the North Pole and recognised a boomerang carved by his dad. The main protagonist unlocks his dad's signature transformation which is an ice beast thing and he can also lift things with his mind. They also have a orange airship and they have a thing kinda like a Pokédex.

Marine Boy? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m0fmy0GS0Y

Is this RedaKai (2011-2013)...?
From Wikipedia:

The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first.


As noted above, the series revolves around three teenagers -- Ky Stax, Boomer and Maya -- on a quest to find Kairu, an alien energy source which enables people (including the three kids) to transform into monsters.
The kids travel around the world in a small orange starship called the X-Scaper.
The kids each carry smartphone-like devices that can track and absorb Kairu energy.
The main kid, Ky, is searching for his missing father, Connor.
Ky can transform into his father's "signature monster," a water elemental called Rip Tide. His friend, Boomer, can transform into an ice elemental called Froztok.
In episode 17, "The Return of Connor Stax," the kids travel to Alaska, the place where Ky's father went missing, and Ky finds a propeller that his father carved out of wood lying in the snow. The propeller is shown being thrown like a boomerang. You can view the relevant scene in the video below.





If you're looking for specific episodes of this on YouTube, note that several of them are incorrectly numbered and titled, so you need to read the title shown within each episode to confirm which one you're watching.
